# Akka Actor LifeCycle

Tags: java, scala, akka, lifecycle, hikaricp

I'm using Akka Java API 2.5.12. I want to implement *push sender*. I use infinite loop with one second delay and in each iteration I fetch 50 pushes from database using Hikari Datasource Connection Pool. Then I iterate over this list of 50 pushes and in each iteration I create new Actor in this way:

```
final ActorRef pushSenderActor = system.actorOf(PushSenderAktor.props());
pushSenderActor.tell(push, ActorRef.noSender());
```

Then **PushSenderAktor** play their role and send push asynchronously.

My question is: *Do I need to stop an actor after he has performed a push sending by  `context().stop(getSelf());` method, or this actor will kill himself after executing his `createReceive()` method?*
Because I don't want to contain a HollyWood in my ActorSystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to explicitly stop or send a PoisonPill

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#actor-lifecycle

Also consider using the scheduler in a top level actor the the regular work and consider keeping actors around and using them as long term workers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you please provide a simple code example where you keep actor as worker? Do you mean to store them in ArrayList<PushSenderActor>?